# Why is my playback from stereo recording splitted ? Audacity

Tags: recording, stereo, audacity, mixdown

I'm recording vocals and guitar in a stereo recording and when I playback through the headphones when overdubbing it sounds split. I guess this is how it's supposed to be but I'd almost prefer it be blended in stereo **L** and **R**.

Is there a way in [Audacity](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/) to playback the stereo recording (while overdubbing) blended rather than hearing vocals through the **R** and guitar through the **L**?

Lastly, when exporting the final from Audacity, does it end up blending everything equally to **L** and **R**, or are the separate tracks played back differently via **L** and **R**?

Comment: If you're recording guitar & vocals from 2 separate mono inputs, you ought to be recording to 2 mono tracks, not one stereo - then you can pan & balance them how you like afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Are you recording your guitar mic and vocal mic to separate tracks? You should NOT be using "stereo" until the final mix-down. Then you can take each separate track and PAN the image to wherever you wish on the Left-to-Right stereo panorama.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind is make a quad-channel wave where you have a copy of your 2 mono tracks - the end resuld should be a fake quad mix

If using a DAW like Cubase, import the wave, split it in to L and R and set the audio track to MONO - this will give you a fake stereo mix

Comment: I'm not sure  this answer understand the question (Seems like OP wants a completely mono mix).